# Sugar ORM - Update record but ignore fields if null value

Tags: android, sugarorm

I am using Sugar ORM in my Android app. My data comes from the server, but some of the models have extra fields that are populated on the device side. When I refresh my data, my device-populated fields are overwritten with null values.

Currently, I am doing a database query to see if that object already exists. If it does, I save the fields that I need to my new object, then call the save() method. There has to be a better way and any help would be appreciated!

I am using Jackson to parse the json response. I have set @JsonIgnore on the fields that aren't coming from the api, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Please provide your entity and save code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to save information and leave some fields empty?
If that's the case, use setters and getters to store the information of your object (ex. `public void setName()`, `public String getName()`) and set only the values you have using ifs

```
if (json.name.length>0)
    object.setName(json.name)
```

After that use `.save()` in case of a new entity, or `.commit()` in case of an update.

Answer (score 0):

@JsonIgnore wont work cause @Ignore is the annotation provided by Sugar ORM, but ignore is ment for completely leaving the field out of the mysql.

What you should do is very similar to your own aproach. Before using save while comparing both objects, set the atributes from the local object to the server object, and then save it.

Is you are going to do this a lot you should maybe want to @Overrida the save method in a special class where you initialy extends sugar orm, and then every other model is extended to that class instead.